# xz compression not available - yum error on centos

Tags: php, centos6, compression

I want to update my php to new version.
Dealing with this source: https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/#comment-139854

And now I can't use yum commands.
Anytime when I'm trying install something or update I receive:  xz compression not available.

PHP was not updated of course but I need to.

I hope you will help me with this.
My OS: CentOS 6.5 (Plesk 12) in OVH (VPS).

Comment: You have an administration control panel installed, which makes all kinds of odd changes to system, and then you try to manually upgrade PHP. I think the only reasonable way to get the system working again is to restore latest working backup. And, to upgrade PHP, you want to contact OVH / Plesk support on how to do it with Plesk.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact ovh but I don't think they can halp me with. So I can upgrade my php using plesk?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to a corrupt epel-release repo file.

Try `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel`, then `yum remove epel-release` and install a correct one.

Comment: Command error: No such option: -r

Comment: @gicu What do you mean ?

Comment: I received this error after pasting your command No such option: -r

Comment: Are you actually using the command line ? There's no reason this would fail, it's the most basic command. Except if you have set up weird aliases.

Comment: [root@vps133375 ~]# yum remove epel-release
Wczytane wtyczki: fastestmirror
Ustawianie procesu usuwania
Brak wyników dla parametru: epel-release
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Błąd: xz compression not available     (some commands is in PL language)

Comment: @gicu You need to remove the cached files with the rm command.  LZMA compression is used for EPEL 7 repo metadata and requires a LZMA  lib but cross repository import should not happen. Also, don't use cpanel / plesk or all this crap.

Comment: Ok, when I put paste this command: rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel   - nothing happened. What should I do now? Forgive me I'm not to good with this :)

Comment: @gicu Let's continue in a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21982/xz-compression-not-available-yum-error-on-centos) to avoid spamming this answer.

Comment: I can't: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. :-P So because rules and FAQ I have to spam here :-)